# Fail to generate URL information in typeset bib item when using bibliography style unsrt

Tags: bibtex

```
@online{H11,
  author = {climate.weather.gc.ca},
  title = {{Climate Data }Hourly Data},
  year = 2014,
  url = {http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climateData/hourlydata.
"timeframe=1\&Prov=NS\&StationID=43403\&hlyRange=2004-09-247C2015-09-28\&Year=2014\&Month=1\&Day=1,2,..,30},
 }
```

What I get not complete details:

> [11] climate.weather.gc.ca. Climate Data hourly data, 2014.

Comment: Any help ,please.

Comment: With what? What's the question? You need to choose a style which supports `url`. The standard BibTeX styles don't do that. You've not provided a complete example, so it is hard to know but the `unsrt` probably means you're using a standard style without support for online identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

The `unsrt` bibliography style is more than 20 years old by now. It was designed in a time before online materials were widely available, let alone considered to be objects that might get cited and show up in bibliographies.

Rather than hack the `unsrt` style to make it recognize a field called `url`, you should consider switching to a newer style that already recognizes this field. I suggest you start with the `unsrtnat` style. It is distributed with the `natbib` package and reimplements the `unsrt` style, and it recognizes and prints out fields such as `url`, `eid`, `issn`, and `isbn`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@online{H11,
  author = {climate.weather.gc.ca},
  title = {{Climate Data }Hourly Data},
  year = 2014,
  url = {http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climateData/hourlydata.
"timeframe=1\&Prov=NS\&StationID=43403\&hlyRange=2004-09-247C2015-09-28\&Year=2014\&Month=1\&Day=1,2,..,30},
 }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}
\cite{H11}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```